# Button click event not getting fired when arguments are passed

Tags: javascript, button, reactjs, typescript, onclick

I have this button click event at which I call a method which takes arguments. Below is how I assign the onClick event.

```
 <button value="My Message" style={ buttonStyle } onClick= {() => this.myScanButtonClicked('Name') }>Send NameScan</button>
```

Below is the signature of the myScanButtonClicked which is inside the same class.

```
myScanButtonClicked = (item: string) => {
}
```

When remove the method argument it gets called. But with the argument, the method is not getting called on button click. But it gets executed at page load. I cannot figure out what's wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried the below shown way of calling it as well, but still no use.

```
onClick= {() => this.myScanButtonClicked.bind(this,'Mark') }
```

Comment: @Boky thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
onClick= {this.myScanButtonClicked.bind(this,'Mark')}

myScanButtonClicked(item, event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(item); //Should be Mark
}
```